# Nginx can ping itself but cannot connect from anywhere else

Tags: nginx, centos

I recently set up an web server on an old PC. I installed centOS, mySQL, PHP and Nginx. When I configured Nginx and started the web server I couldn't connect from a PC on the same router or outside the router using the IP address. I have set up port forwarding on the TP Link router I use like this

rule 1
application HTTP_Server
protocol ALL
start port 80
end port   80
local ip address 192.168.1.101

My /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file has

```
server {
listen              80 default_server;
server_name         server.com;

charset koi8-r;

location / {
    root            /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index           index.html index.htm index.php;
}

error_page          404          /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root            /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

error_page          500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root            /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    root            /usr/share/nginx/html;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

I have little experience with Linux and less with Nginx, I would really appreciate any help anyone could give. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firewall which was set to default on centOS wasn't allowing connections on port 80. By adding the lines

> -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

to the files

> /etc/sysconfig/iptables
>
> /etc/sysconfig/ip6tables

allows http and https connections to my server

Answer (score 0):

To connect using the IP address add the IP to the server name

```
server_name server.com 192.168.1.101;
```

Then restart nginx and it should work if you access `http://192.168.1.101` from inside the local network.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mohammad, I tried this but same result. I think it might be the router, I've had problems with it recently and updated the firmware, ever since the speed has been up and down, maybe port forwarding isn't working on it

Comment: then the problem isn't in the router or the ip, you need to make sure that the service is actually running, ssh to that computer and run `sudo service nginx status`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Thanks! That's what worked for me. My nginx was `dead but pid file still exists`. A restart solved the situation.